# Clojure : apply keys to every sequence of sequence

Tags: clojure

I'm new to the Clojure universe and I have a problem.
I got a LazySeq which looks like this (longer in fact)

```
values = (("Brand1" "0") ("Brand2" "15") ("Brand3" "12"))
```

I also defined `field` as

```
fields = [:Brand :Sale]
```

I would like to have finally at least

```
({:Brand "Brand1 :Sale "0"} {:Brand "Brand2 :Sale "15"} {:Brand "Brand3 :Sale "12"})
```

I tried several things (apply, interleave, reduce, into and combinations of that) but I get every time an unexpected result.

Is that possible ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you're right: you have to `interleave` and then add them all to map. But you should do it for every collection in `values`. That means you need to use `map`:

```
(let [values '(("Brand1" "0") ("Brand2" "15") ("Brand3" "12"))
      fields [:Brand :Sale]]
  (map #(apply hash-map (interleave fields %)) values))
```

output:

```
({:Sale "0", :Brand "Brand1"} 
 {:Sale "15", :Brand "Brand2"} 
 {:Sale "12", :Brand "Brand3"})
```

another variant is to do it like this:

```
(let [values '(("Brand1" "0") ("Brand2" "15") ("Brand3" "12"))
      fields [:Brand :Sale]]
  (map #(into {} (map vector fields %)) values))
```

Comment: Tanks a lot, it worked! I totally missed the % thing, I should review the book. I see the logic of the code ! Happy Christmas !

Comment: Use `zipmap` instead of `apply hashmap ...`

Answer (score 4):

You should use `zipmap`

```
(map (partial zipmap fields) values)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this thing but did not knew about partial, works too ! Is this more efficient ?